Why does this return an "out of range" error when working with a string-type list?
Below is the code below for a C# Console Application Hangman game.
I would like to save the individual characters of the sentence the user has to guess in a list so that correctly guessed letters can be stored.
List<string> lstSentence = new List<string>();
List<string> lstGuesses = new List<string>();
lstSentence.Capacity = sSentence.Length;


for (int i = 0; i < sSentence.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(sSentence[i]))
    {
        sRevealedSentence += "*";
        lstSentence[i] = "*"; //Error appears here
    }

    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(sSentence[i]))
    {
        sRevealedSentence += " ";
        lstSentence[i] = " "; //Error appears here too
    }
}

I tried to store the individual characters of the sentence the user has to guess as asterisks and spaces to indicate the length of the words in the sentence.

Setting the capacity for a list doesn't change its size. Look at lstSentence.Count - it will still be 0, so lstSentence[0] is still invalid. You should use lstSentence.Add instead.

So here, you are creating an empty list here,

List lstSentence = new List();

but in below line you are trying to access the value at index 'i' of this list and then assign a new value "*"

lstSentence[i] = "*"; //Error appears here

you created an empty list to start with, which is why you are getting error in this line.
So possible solution would be to push these values in the list instead of assigning them by index
OR
create a list with some random values and then assign "*" or " " depending on your logic.

If 'sSentence' always contains letters and/or white spaces, you can re-write your code to:
List<string> lstSentence = new List<string>();
List<string> lstGuesses = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < sSentence.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(sSentence[i]))
    {
        sRevealedSentence += "*";
        lstSentence.Add("*");
    }
    else
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(sSentence[i]))
        {
            sRevealedSentence += " ";
            lstSentence.Add(" ");
        }
    }
}

If you prefer to have a predefined list, you can use the following code (Remember that Enumerable requires System.Linq in your project).
// lstSentence initialization with ""s
List<string> lstSentence = Enumerable.Repeat("",sSentence.Length).ToList();
List<string> lstGuesses = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < sSentence.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(sSentence[i]))
    {
        sRevealedSentence += "*";
        lstSentence[i] = "*";
    }
    else
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(sSentence[i]))
        {
            sRevealedSentence += " ";
            lstSentence[i] = " "; 
        }
     }

When a character is different from a letter or white space:
a) first approach will ignore it and 'lstSentence' will have fewer elements than the number of characters in 'sSentence' and
b) second approach will keep 'lstSentence' with same size of 'sSentence' and will insert the default character ("", defined in list initialization) into 'lstSentence'.

Unless you're doing something more with the lists which requires that they be lists, you can use arrays of stings instead:
string[] lstSentence = new string[sSentence.Length];

This way it is easier to declare the size of the array early
